# SharePoint 2013 - What in SharePoint requires meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

For SharePoint 2013 Publishing pages, what requires 
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"/>` 
to run properly? Can I simply remove it from master and assume that nothing out of the box will break?  or did Microsoft put this in the  for a specific reason?

Can I live without it if my IE browser support is 9+

...I notice that if i remove this from the master template manually, and upload my master template,  share-point forces it to render the content in ie9.  How can we remove the force? Some web applications need IE11 to render as IE11, not IE9 or IE10.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">` tag is to force IE to render in IE10 compatibility mode.

If your farm has been migrated from an older SharePoint version, it may not be forced to the last IE version (or edge). This is done to avoid unexpeted behaviour (maily CSS and HTML standards) by upgrading the farm or a new version of IE was released and installed.

Back to the question **How can we remove the force?**: I don't know if it possible, it think it's not. But even if it would, you shouldn't.
When a new version of IE was released, the master page should edited/updated by hand and tested. Now the standard browser is (should be) Edge, the tag should be `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`. Up to some months ago I figured out problems with the `Multiple lines of text` as Richtext fields, now seems to be fixed. However, there might be other problems, I have to check it too.

In our farm we had it forced to IE10, now I'm working (testing) in order to force it to Edge.

In your case, IE10 will work for sure. If you want to set it to Edge, you have to test your customizations.